# React Router - Adding a trailing slash or URL param doesn't render components outside of Switch statement

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I'm currently setting up Routing on this project and it all renders out correctly when I visit each route, but once I add a trailing slash or an extra URL param, such as `/reset_password/:token`, it renders only the component attached to that Route, but any components outside of it aren't anymore, such as the `<Header />` and `<ColorBar />`.

I've tried wrapping the entire application with the `Router` component, but it doesn't seem to do the trick either. No matter where I place the Router, it produces the same result.

```
     <ThemeProvider theme={Inspinia}>
        <S.App>
          <BackgroundGradients />
          <S.PageContainer>
            <Router history={history}>
              <ColorBar />
              <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
                <Route path="/forgot_password" component={ForgotPasswordPage} />
                <Route path="/reset_password" component={ResetPasswordPage} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/deal" component={Deal} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </S.PageContainer>
        </S.App>
      </ThemeProvider>
```

What I'm looking for in the end is that having a route with URL params such as `/reset_password/:token` will not only render the component itself but also the Components above it as well like `<ColorBar />` and `<Header />`. In this case, `<ColorBar />` and `<Header />` and all the other components above the switch statement are constants I need displaying throughout the entire application, regardless of the route a user may be in.

Comment: it is only rendering ResetPasswordPage for  `/reset_password/:token` ?

Comment: @McRist Yeah if I `/reset_password/:token` as the route, it'll only render the component pertaining to that route (`ResetPasswordPage`). The components above the Switch component simply won't show at all, but they are still in the document when I inspect it.

Comment: just check if there isn't any css issue, if they are still in the document while inspecting.

Comment: I have created an example with `react-router` see [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-night-qxh69)

Comment: In your example, `Header` and `Menu`, which are outside of `Switch` are rendering on every single route/view. That is your intention right? To render `Header` and `Menu` and every single route/view in addition to the matched route/component?

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi Thank you for the link!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky That's right. The idea is that they're just Header components that can be seen throughout the app. It does work as intended when I'm not visiting a route that has a trailing slash or extra URL param like `/reset_password/:token`, but once I do it only renders that one component and doesn't display what's above it anymore.

Comment: You should update the Code Sandbox with your specific code to allow to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I can't seem to replicate the issue on CodeSandbox. I'm thinking it might be an issue with my CSS, but it's strange since it works just fine up until there's a trailing slash involved.